# How to be notified when the user reach the 8 waypoints limitation when adding a new point into a Direction

Tags: google-maps

I have been working on an open source Street View Player (http://StreetViewPlayer.org), and I have a question regarding adding a new point into a new Direction.

When the user add a new location, I need to know if the user has reached the 8 waypoints limitation.

Is there a way to be notified ?

Can anybody give me some insight about this?

Here is a simple code to illustrate this (add several points until you reach the 8 waypoints limitations):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      var map;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: 35.694346, lng: -79.796409},
          zoom: 13
        });
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
        var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
          draggable: true,
          map: map
        });
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

        directionsService.route({
          origin:      {lat: 35.694346, lng: -79.796409},
          destination: {lat: 34.964737, lng: -80.060434},
          waypoints: [
            {location: {lat: 35.559346, lng: -80.089850}, stopover: true},
            {location: {lat: 35.356588, lng: -79.899915}, stopover: true},
          ],
          optimizeWaypoints: false,
          travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
        }, function(response, status) {
          if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
          } else {
            window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
          }
        });
        function show( v ) {
            if ( v != undefined )
                console.log( "new waypoint is # " + v );
        }
        directionsDisplay.addListener('directions_changed', function() {
            var newDir = directionsDisplay.getDirections();
            console.log( newDir );
            show( newDir.request.Xc );
            show( newDir.request.Yc );
            show( newDir.request.Uc );
            show( newDir.request.Vc );
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The number of total points (origin, destination, plus any waypoints) equal to the length of the `geocoded_waypoints` array.  Subtract 2 from that to get the number of "waypoints" in the directions request.

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: 35.694346,
      lng: -79.796409
    },
    zoom: 13
  });
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    draggable: true,
    map: map
  });
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

  directionsService.route({
    origin: {
      lat: 35.694346,
      lng: -79.796409
    },
    destination: {
      lat: 34.964737,
      lng: -80.060434
    },
    waypoints: [{
      location: {
        lat: 35.559346,
        lng: -80.089850
      },
      stopover: true
    }, {
      location: {
        lat: 35.356588,
        lng: -79.899915
      },
      stopover: true
    }, ],
    optimizeWaypoints: false,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  }, function(response, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    } else {
      window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    }
  });

  function show(v) {
    if (v != undefined)
      console.log("new waypoint is # " + v);
  }
  directionsDisplay.addListener('directions_changed', function() {
    var newDir = directionsDisplay.getDirections();
    document.getElementById('waypoints').innerHTML = newDir.geocoded_waypoints.length;
    console.log("there are " + (newDir.geocoded_waypoints.length - 2) + " waypoints");
    console.log(newDir);
    show(newDir.request.Xc);
    show(newDir.request.Yc);
    show(newDir.request.Uc);
    show(newDir.request.Vc);
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="waypoints"></div>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: The question was: is there a way to be notified? And unless I am missing something, the event "directions_changed" is not fired in the case a 9th waypoint is tentatively added to the direction.

Comment: The `directions_changed` fires every time a 9th waypoint attempts to be added.